# Unable to start supervisor deamon

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, supervisord

I am getting following error while restarting supervisord. I searched for it and tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and `easy_install --upgrade pip` but nothing is working out.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord start
Starting supervisord: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/supervisord", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: supervisor==3.3.1
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I am using Amazon AMI instance. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I launched a new Amazon EC2 instance with the Amazon Linux AMI and did:

```
sudo easy_install supervisor
```

It worked fine.

Based on: http://supervisord.org/installing.html

Comment: HI @John I too had the same problem but your solution does not work for me.

Comment: @DEV -- Did you launch a new Amazon Linux instance, and run the above command? Feel free to start a new Question if you'd like assistance.